# c# How to get dynamically created object

Tags: c#

I have a method that creates client and i have another method that must use created specific client but i dont know how to get that specific client.

```
   private void CreateClient(string username, string token,string mail, string mailpass)
   {
            Client client = new Client();
            //...
   }
```

```
  private void CreateLive(string username)
  {
            //How to get createclient method's client.
            //...
  }
```

Comment: "*I have a method that creates client and i have another method that must use created specific client but i dont know how to get that specific client.*" - what does this mean? Can you be a little more descriptive. Are the methods in different classes?

Comment: As you can see i am creating a client dynamically `Client client = new Client();` but i want to use that client in another method.

Comment: Store them in a `Dictionary<string,Client>` maybe ?

Comment: Im a beginner self-learner coder, do you have any example for that? Thanks.

Comment: The first question you need to ask yourself is, what makes one client different to the another, is there anyway way you can distinguish clients from one another by name or key or something. Or is there only ever one client?

Comment: How is Client client = new Client(); dynamic?

Comment: One client means one account, so im making an account management application. Afaik i cant name the clients.

Comment: Yes i want to access/use created client from another method.

Comment: I just want it to be accessible in `CreateLive` method.

Comment: @my-name-is-not-important Thus you can use the @.quaabaam answer and adapt it to your needs. I hope this can help you to enjoy C# coding: [How do I improve my knowledge in C#](http://www.ordisoftware.com/files/stack-overflow/CsharpBegin.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Generally you want to have your function provide a return value. In this case your `CreateClient` function can return your created `Client` object;

```
// updated to return Client object
private Client CreateClient(string username, string token,string mail, string mailpass)
{
    Client client = new Client(); // create client
    return client; // return client to caller
}

private void CreateLive(string username)
{    
    Client myClient = CreateClient(username, "sometoken","myname@someplace.com","1234");
    // now I can do things with myClient ...
}
```